# I am trying to program a checking program ( which is part of a bigger project ). Given a 2D Array of integers of size[3][3]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The method should return true if the array has no same or repeat of any numbers and false if there is a similar number in the 2D array.

Here's what I have done so far...
The problem is that I when I move to the 2nd Array, the first index is selected and checked and thus returns false. Same case with the 3rd Array.
How do I fix this?

A good checking process suggestion is also appreciated.

```
    public static boolean checkArray ( int[][] array){
    int index = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){

        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
            int element = array[i][j]; //Select an array one by one

            //checking row of the seleceted number
            for(int k=0+j; k<array[i].length-1;k++){
                if(element == array[i][k+1]){
                    System.out.println("Yeet1");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //selected number compares to 2nd Array
            index =1;
            for(int l=0; l<array[index].length;l++){
                if(array[1][0] == element){
                    continue;
                }

                if(element == array[index][l]){
                    System.out.println("Yeet2");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //selected number with 3rd Array
            index =2;
            for(int m=0; m<array[index].length;m++){
                if(element == array[index][m]){
                    System.out.println("Yeet3");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

return true;
}//Method ends here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a limited input size. Go through the 2d array and put each integer into a HashSet. If the size of the set is less than 9 in the end, it contained duplicates.